# Copy system bundle to a Mac on network?

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, filesystem

I screwed up while using Monolingual and removed the "AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle". Before I realized what happened, I logged out and now I can't type a password to log back in.

I have tried to copy the bundle to the right location, using Sharing but I get "not enough write permissions." I tried using `scp` in Terminal but I get "no such file" on all the bundle contents.

What is the best way to copy a bundle to one of the System folders `/Systems/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` from one Mac to another over the network?

I know that I can probably restore from a boot disk but I'd prefer to just do it this way if possible.

Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy your "AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle" to a system folder you need "root permission!" use `cp` (copy) or `mv` (move) with `sudo` (super user) to copy files.

If you let's say try to copy folders or files that have a recursive structure/architecture you need to add the `-r` flag, like so: `cp -r ~/Desktop/myFolderA` ..

```
sudo cp ~/yourPath/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle /Systems/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/
```

It is always a good idea imho, to have a second partition ready on the same HDD in order to copy files back and forth, if needed, or at least to have a second user account with sufficient permissions.

Comment: Thanks! So I was trying `sudo cp -r /System/Library/"Keyboard Layouts"/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle /Volumes/Mini/System/Library/"Keyboard Layouts"/` and I was getting a bunch of "No such file or directory"s.

Comment: i see. are you certain that your 'dir' is valid?! i can't see a typo so far. try to drag the .bundle you want to copy into terminal.app after "sudo -r" and then type in your location.

Comment: Thanks. Should `/Volumes/<Name of Mac>/` work? Because the very first error i get is No such directory on that location.

Comment: you are welcome!! why not drag and drop both locations into terminal (if possible over your network from mac01), to make sure, there are no typos and the path is correct.

Comment: Still not working. I can copy the file to another location on the volume, but not to /System/Library. Even with sudo.

Comment: ..because you get "not enough write permissions" message i suppose! If you get "No such file or directory" message, then i don't understand what is wrong, if the path used is accurate. i am curious though if you'd succeed, using firewire connection.

Comment: I was trying to fix this before reinstalling OS X but last night I broke down and just reinstalled which worked perfectly. However, this *should* have worked so I'll accept :)

Comment: To bad, that it didn't work out for you in the end!! Thank you for your appreciation Don! Cheers!